# how we can refresh or reset a form using javascript funcion

Tags: javascript

how we can refresh or reset a form using javascript funcion that function should be called on another form textbox element  element on same page . function should be called on onclick event.  i will tried form.rest() function in javascript and its not working for me. Please try to sort out my problem . I did this two changes but its not able to reset my form field .

```
$('#myform').trigger("reset");
```

or i was tried  another function but it also not work

```
$('myform')[0].reset();
```

Comment: You might wanna post the code of your form.

Comment: [Ref](http://www.javascript-coder.com/files/javascript-clear-form/javascript-clear-form-example.html) Hope it will work for u

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(function () {
    $("#reset").on("click", function () {
        $(':input', '#demo')
            .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
            .val('')
            .removeAttr('checked')
            .removeAttr('selected');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="demo">
  <input type="text"><br>
  <input type="text"><br>
  <input type="text"><br>
 <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: welcome mate :) but i am going to make history in `stakeoverflow` which answer accepted with -1 vote :P

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').reset();
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#myForm').reset();
```